# How can I apply tpad filter to the end of a trimmed video stream?

Tags: ffmpeg

I've tried `-vf trim=end=20,tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=2` with a 25 seconds video, but the clone frames are added before trimming.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only way I could figure was trimming to an intermediate file:
`ffmpeg -i input -codec copy -to 20 intermed`
And then applying `-vf tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=2` to `intermed`.

Please tell me if there is a simpler, cleaner or more elegant solution.

Comment: I can not follow your reasoning. end in trim means first timestamp of input that will be trimmed from now on. If you need to trim at some other spot you will need to adjust end value to some other, slightly higher value.

Comment: I mean, in my first attempt the pad filter is apparently being applied before the video is trimmed, although it comes after in the command line. It seems that clone frames are added from 25 to 27 seconds, and then the video is trimmed at 20 seconds. No effect of the tpad filter is visible. If I cut the video into an intermediate file and apply tpad I get the expected result.

Comment: You never posted ffmpeg version you use, this is very important information missing here.

Comment: @PaulB.Mahol Sorry, I am using version 4.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

I've repeated my test and it just worked as expected, with the same ffmpeg install. Certainly I was doing something wrong, or just confusing things.
Sorry, I will be more careful next time.